# Property 'key' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<Customer>'

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to create customer data base but I am getting an error

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists'

```typescript
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomersList();
  }

  getCustomersList() {
    this.customerService.getCustomersList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(customers => {
      this.customers = customers;
    });
  }

  deleteCustomers() {
    this.customerService.deleteAll().catch(err =>
    console.log(err));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this error by installing the **npm** below

```
npm i firebase@8.3.1
```